# Определить находится ли точка в области

Tags: c#, геометрия

Точка находится внутри области, попробывал несколько методов, все определяють, что она извне.

Проверка:

```
public bool IsPointInPolygon(Point2D[] polygon, Point2D testPoint)
    {
        var result = false;
        var j = polygon.Count() - 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < polygon.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (polygon[i].Y < testPoint.Y && polygon[j].Y >= testPoint.Y || polygon[j].Y < testPoint.Y && polygon[i].Y >= testPoint.Y)
            {
                if (polygon[i].X + (testPoint.Y - polygon[i].Y) / (polygon[j].Y - polygon[i].Y) * (polygon[j].X - polygon[i].X) < testPoint.X)
                {
                    result = !result;
                }
            }
            j = i;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Точка:

> (-6616.47, 6802.17)

Область:

> (-4838.07, 5372.37) (-4838.07, 7310.17)
>
> (-8497.47, 7411.77) (-4736.47,7411.77)
>
> (-4735.47, 5271.77) (-8496.47, 5271.77)
>
> (-8598.07, 5169.17) (-8598.07", 7513.37)

Comment: Область всегда прямоугольник параллельный координатным осям? Каковы условия (не)совпадения угловых точек?

Comment: Странное условие. Если точка попала внутрь - то надо же остановиться, а не дальше шпарить перебором, не?

Comment: @AK Она может попасть по одной стороне, по другой нет. Например, точка будет перед сегментом f, если бы проверка сразу возвращала она бы вернула true потому что перед сегментом i.

Comment: Это задание на знание литературы. Открываете учебник, находите алгоритм, готово. Ну вот статья даже в Википедии есть про класс этих проблем: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon (считаю что это вопрос под закрытие)

Comment: @sanmai взял алгоритм здесь https://stackoverflow.com/a/39872429/8119425

Comment: Там же на ответ выше другой алгоритм, попробуйте

Comment: В вопросе, написал что попробовал несколько методов, не могу понять причину

Comment: @Adam Hodovanets А почему результат именно так  result = !result;??? У Вас четыре раза инвертируется result, получая, в конце, естественно, значение false… замените на прямое присваивание  result = true;

Comment: я думаю надо замкнуть область а потом использовать pointInPolygonTest, который у Вас в коде

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов в коде все корректно, это известынй алгоритм на принадлежность точки полигону, считает кол-во пересечений луча, выпущенного из точки с ребрами многогранника, если кол-во пересечений нечетное, то точка внутри http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/Diagram_1.gif

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, ясно, спасибо

Comment: замкнуть область нужно при помощи нахождения пар точке которые ближе друг к другу, но это не точно